# Firefox top blackline

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, cinnamon

While using Firefox in Linux Mint 19.3, I have an issue as shown here:

[image]

When maximising the browser, the several pixel height line appears at the top of the screen. "Title bar" and "Drag Space" options are disabled, but I can still use that black line to drag the program down to un-maximise the app.
This can only be seen in Firefox and no other app has a problem like this. I tried to get help from [the Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=316103), but no luck.

Comment: It seems the window isn't properly anchored. Might have to do with you customizing your Mint taskbar, like, using a compact theme or something like that. Is your screen showing its native resolution or a custom one?

Comment: It is default native 1920x1080 resolution. I also tried to change back height of taskbar to default (or at least bigger) but the black line still persists with the same height :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in using Ant theme for "Windows Border"